# Take a subset from a complex object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

How can I take (in JS) all the values inside this nested object except for the last two elements (scenario and total). here an image of the object I have:

[image]

I need an array equal to this one, but without "scenario" and "total" in the 3 nested objects inside.

Comment: You're probably looking for `.filter`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` function

```
array.map(item => {
    delete item.scenario;
    delete item.total;
    return item;
});
```